# How to fix this issue of adding two points in curve secp256k1 of ECDSA?

Tags: android, ecdsa

I got this error:
ava.lang.ClassCastException:            org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECFieldElement$Fp cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.math.ec.custom.sec.SecP256K1FieldElement

once trying to read a public key as a string in android which is retrieved from .pem file as

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n
MIH1MIGuBgcqhkjOPQIBMIGiAgEBMCwGByqGSM49AQECIQD/////////////////
///////////////////+///8LzAGBAEABAEHBEEEeb5mfvncu6xVoGKVzocLBwKb
/NstzijZWfKBWxb4F5hIOtp3JqPEZV2k+/wOEQio/Re0SKaFVBmcR9CP+xDUuAIh
AP////////////////////66rtzmr0igO7/SXozQNkFBAgEBA0IABK5F1KgwnBG3
jVLqtqJ9+uesDOzP00s88bgGyYQen86xLn1iUJxy/qPPmn9WZyfQ+b27UaHNAa09
83BuGKHERAE=
\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

This key from type secp256k1

and this is the code part of reading a public key :

```
       Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);

       Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());                                                
        Reader rdr = new StringReader (keys[seletedTFE]);
        Object parsed = new     org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser(rdr).readObject();
        ECPublicKey key = (ECPublicKey) new    org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPublicKey((Subje.ctPublicKeyInfo) parsed);

         ECPoint P = key.getQ();
```

and the error because of this point: of adding C1 with C2 and it says that C2 of type ECpointfp while C2 of type ECElementFieldsecp256k1

```
     ECPoint C1;
     ECPoint C2;
     ECPoint C3;
     C2 = P.multiply(beta);
     C3 = C1.add(C2)   ;
```

and this code works with prime256v1 and secp256r1 ,but I need to use secp256k1,so  how to solve this issue ?